# ImageInput only works the second time [3.0.0-alpha only]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

long description but simple issue here!

I'm trying to create a basic image input form Drag and drop is cool, but regular OS dialog would be good enough. However in this case they both act the same way.

Here's the code:

```
const MediaLibrarieCreate = props => (
    <Create {...props}>
        <SimpleForm defaultValue={defaultValue}>
            <TextInput source="title" />
            <ImageInput source="file" accept="image/*" >
                <ImageField source="url" title="title"/>
            </ImageInput>
        </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
);
```

And what that displays:
[image: basic react-admin image input form]

**The problem is** that when I drop a file (or select from dialog) **the first time, it doesn't work**. Then, if I do it again (not reloading the page, not changing anything) it does accept the input.

[image: filled react-admin image input]

Now this is curious so I tried to log the `onDrop` events:

```
<ImageInput source="file" accept="image/*" options={{
    onDrop: console.log
}} >
```

Which logs **even on the first try**:

```
[File]
    0: File {
        lastModified: 1566296107287
        lastModifiedDate: Tue Aug 20 2019 12:15:07 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) {}
        name: "493ca08cec56142508776cab706c07ca.jpg"
        preview: "blob:http://localhost:3002/32f56e71-117b-4631-90aa-c0b312864ccf"
        size: 58380
        type: "image/jpeg"
        webkitRelativePath: ""
    }
SyntheticEvent {
    dispatchConfig: {…}, 
    _targetInst: FiberNode, 
    _dispatchListeners: ƒ, 
    _dispatchInstances: FiberNode, 
    nativeEvent: Event, 
    …
}
```

But if I try to log *from within* the `<ImageField>` then I see **it only receives props on the second try**, and behaves exactly as described above with the screenshots, only displaying the image on the second try:

```
const Test = props => {
    console.log(props)
    return <ImageField title="title" {...props}/>
}

// ...

<ImageInput source="file" accept="image/*">
    <Test source="url"/>
</ImageInput>
```

Which logs nothing on the first try, but logs this on the second:

```
{
    className: "ImageInput-preview-213"
    record: {
        rawFile: File
            lastModified: 1566296107287
            lastModifiedDate: Tue Aug 20 2019 12:15:07 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) {}
            name: "493ca08cec56142508776cab706c07ca.jpg"
            preview: "blob:http://localhost:3002/c99da6a6-a506-4c25-b8f2-62b3c4f9c966"
            size: 58380
            type: "image/jpeg"
            webkitRelativePath: ""
            __proto__: File
        }
        url: "blob:http://localhost:3002/c99da6a6-a506-4c25-b8f2-62b3c4f9c966"
    }
    source: "url"
```

This is in the context of a pretty default React-Admin app. Not a custom one, nothing was done with redux, only the dataProvider is custom (but isn't involved here).

Could anyone point me in the right direction as to **how to make the ImageInput work on the first interaction**?

Thanks

---

- macOS 10.14.6
- Chrome 76.0.3809.100
- react-admin 3.0.0-alpha.2

Comment: Hi, in configuration: Windows 10, Chrome 76.0.3809.100 / Firefox 56.02, react-admin: 2.9.5 this behavior is not observed. Could the problem be with the browser or its plug-ins?

Comment: @MaxAlex I'm on macOS 10.14.6 /  Chrome 76.0.3809.100, react-admin 3.0.2-alpha. I'm having issues with firefox / safari so I can only test on Chrome. But it's up to date and I'm not using any plug-in...

Comment: @MaxAlex Ok so I've tested on Windows Pro 1803, Firefox Quantum 68.0.2 -  64bits, react-admin 3.0.2-alpha => the issue is reproduced.

Also tried macOS 10.14.6 / Chrome 76.0.3809.100, react-admin 2.9.6 => the issue isn't there.

Comment: Yes, react-admin 3.0.2 looks like a very early version, try opening Issue on github.