# Payload passed to dataProvider doesn't contain File from ImageInput [3.0.0-alpha only]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I'm making a react-admin app and I'd like to be able to handle file uploads. I have read the appropriate documentation on [decorating-your-data-provider-example-of-file-upload](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#decorating-your-data-provider-example-of-file-upload) and I already have a custom `dataProvider`.

The problem is that said **`dataProvider` never receives any info about files passed to `<ImageInput>`**.

Here's a simplified view of the app's structure:

```
import { fetchUtils } from 'react-admin';

const jsonServerProvider = (apiUrl, httpClient = fetchUtils.fetchJson) => {
    return (type, resource, payload) => {
        console.log('making API request', type, resource, payload)

        const options = { // ... }
        const url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}/...`;

        return httpClient(url, options)
    }
}

const dataProvider = jsonServerProvider(`${domain}/api/v1`);

const App = () => (
    <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider} >
        <Resource {...MediaLibraries} />
    </Admin>
);
```

And `MediaLibraries` contains a `create` key to the following component:

```
const MediaLibrarieCreate = props => (
    <Create {...props}>
        <SimpleForm defaultValue={defaultValue}>
            <TextInput source="title" />
            <ImageInput source="file" accept="image/*" >
                <ImageField source="url" title="title"/>
            </ImageInput>
        </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
);
```

Now this has an issue addressed in a separate issue ([ImageInput only works the second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57589839/imageinput-only-works-the-second-time)) but the problem here is that this **`<Create>` component doesn't send the `File` payload to the `dataProvider`**.

I can observe that the `File` is passed to the `<ImageInput>` with an extra component:

```
const Test = props => {
    console.log(props)
    return <ImageField title="title" {...props}/>
}

// ...

<ImageInput source="file" accept="image/*">
    <Test source="url"/>
</ImageInput>
```

Which logs the following:

```
{
    className: "ImageInput-preview-213"
    record: {
        rawFile: File
            lastModified: 1566296107287
            lastModifiedDate: Tue Aug 20 2019 12:15:07 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) {}
            name: "493ca08cec56142508776cab706c07ca.jpg"
            preview: "blob:http://localhost:3002/c99da6a6-a506-4c25-b8f2-62b3c4f9c966"
            size: 58380
            type: "image/jpeg"
            webkitRelativePath: ""
            __proto__: File
        }
        url: "blob:http://localhost:3002/c99da6a6-a506-4c25-b8f2-62b3c4f9c966"
    }
    source: "url"
```

But when I click "Save" on the `<Create>` form, the dataProvider doesn't receive any File object. Here's what the `console.log` from the `jsonServerProvider` (shown above) logs:

```
making API request
CREATE
mediaLibraries
{
    data: 
        title: "test CREATE image"
}
```

Whereas I'm expecting the `payload` argument to contain some sort of `file.url`.

Could you help me find what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

---

- macOS 10.14.6
- Chrome 76.0.3809.100
- react-admin 3.0.0-alpha.2